# "Importance" metric for discrete variable value

Tags: estimation, descriptive-statistics, importance

(I am far from an expert in the field of statistics, so I apologize beforehand if my question is irrelevant or my use of any terms is incorrect)

Let's suppose that we have a *discrete* variable $X$, and a set of $n+1$ observations $\{x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n\}$. The values of $X$ may not be numeric and all observations are considered equal with no particular order. Therefore, we can transform the observation set above to a set of $k+1$ value/frequency pairs $\{<v_0, f_0>, <v_1, f_1>,\dots,<v_k, f_k>\}$.

Is there a metric that estimates the "importance" of a specific *value* in this set?

For example, in an observation set where all values exist exactly three times, none can be considered more important than the others. On the other hand, in a set where all but one values exist 3 times, I would want that one value that exists 10 times to be differentiated from the rest. Same with a value that only appears once.

A simple probability calculation, for example, $P(k) = f_k / (n+1)$ would not be of help, because it does not take into account the other values.

I experimented with various combinations/formulas using the various layman-known metrics (mean, standard deviation, maximum, minimum etc), but anything I came up with seemed too arbitrary for me to trust.

I am currently using the standard score of the value frequency as an estimator, but it has a major issue: it's not bounded, and I am not at all sure how to normalize it without unknowingly biasing any results.

I would appreciate any reference to a metric that might get me started, or to any terminology that describes what I'd like to do more accurately, so that I can focus my search.

I would especially appreciate any bounded metrics that can be computed incrementally as new samples are added to the observation set :-)

Comment: I think we may need more information, in particular, what is this metric to be used for? What are the particular characateristics that make a value "important"? For example, what if one value occurs 3 times, and all the other 10 times? What if half occur 3 times and half occur 10?

Comment: @Simon Byrne: The metric would be used to provide (part of) a weight coefficient in a similarity calculation. Conceptually, I'd like to penalise values that are dominant within a population, on the premise that they are not as distinguishing as less frequent ones. The only characteristic I have to work with is the frequency of a value - the value itself does not matter.

Comment: @Simon Byrne: I suppose that a bounded (e.g. within [-1, 1]) metric that could tell me how much does a specific observation deviate from the rest of the population would also do - I could apply it on the value frequency set.

Comment: @thkala: Are you trying to match records based on the similarity of different variables? If so, there is quite a lot of literature on this, usually under the names of "probabilistic matching" or "probabilistic record linkage"

Comment: @Simon Byrne: That *does* sound similar to what I want to do. I'll try these keywords and see if it helps...

Comment: @thkala Research "entropy" while you're at it.  (Entropy can be interpreted as an average "importance" where importance is measured as the negative logarithm of the frequency.)

Comment: This may well be in your list of "layman measures" already tried, but doesn't simply ranking the values by frequency do what you want?